# Private common methods in Ruby Modules

Tags: ruby, oop, module

Apologies, for being a bit noob'ish! :). Is there a way that I can have common private methods to be inside the classes that I have defined in it. For ex, can I have:

```
Module MyMod
 class MyClass
   ...
   method1()
 end
 class MyClass2
  ...
  method1()
 end
 private
 def method1()
   ...
 end
end
```

I am guessing, calling them as follows:

```
a = MyMod::MyClass.new
```

But it gives me an error, that method1 is not available.

Something along these lines? I tried using self class but doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try send a.send(:method1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way

```
module MyModule
  class A
    def my_method_a
      MyModule.my_method
    end
  end

  class B
    def my_method_b
      MyModule.my_method
    end
  end

  private
  module_function
  def my_method
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

and
 then

```
a = MyModule::A.new 
a.my_method_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have that for e.g.

```
module MyModule
  class A
    def my_method_a
      my_method
    end
  end

  class B
    def my_method_b
      my_method
    end
  end

  private
  def my_method
    puts "hello"
  end
end
a = A.new
a.my_method_a
output => "hello"
```

But you won't be able to use a.my_method as it is a private method.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. If I try something like: `a = MyModule::A.new
a.my_method_a`. It gives me error on `my_method`.